# What Spring annotations would I use to mix GET and POST variables as arguments on the same method?

Tags: java, spring

I've got a method that looks something like this:

```
@RestController
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope("request")
@RequestMapping(value = "/path/to", produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public class MyController {

    Thing thing;

    @RequestMapping("/myMethod")
    @ResponseBody
    public String myMethod(
                @RequestParam(value="storeIds", required=false) List<String> storeIds,
                @RequestParam(value="startDate") Date startDate,
                @RequestParam(value="endDate") Date endDate
    ) throws Exception {
        JSONObject json = thing.getJson(startDate, endDate, storeIds);
        return json.toString();
    }

}
```

Right now this accepts three parameters, as you can see, and they all come in as GET variables. What I'd like to do is have the startDate and endDate parameters still come in as GET variables, but the storeIds parameters come in as a POST variable. I'm concerned that if I just change the @RequestMapping annotation to the POST method, then it will expect all three parameters to be POST variables instead.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm asking for?

Comment: What do you think a GET parameter is? What do you think a POST parameter is?

Comment: I come from a PHP background, so what I mean is this: GET variables are passed in as part of the query string; POST variables are passed in as data with the request (but not as the URL itself).

Comment: `@RequestParam` checks for both. You can use it regardless of the HTTP request type.

Comment: Oh, good to know! I'll test it out but I think that's the correct answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between a `GET` request and a `POST` request, aside from the implied semantics of "getting" vs. "posting" (and associated likely consequences with respect to caching, reloading, etc.), is simply that a `POST` request has a body, while a `GET` request does not. (And even with a `POST` request, the body can be empty: a zero-length body is valid.) This means that a `GET` request can *only* take parameters via the URL, whereas a `POST` request can take parameters *either* via the URL *or* via the body (or some via the one and some via the other).

From the comments above, I gather that you use the term "GET variable" to mean a URL parameter, even in a POST request; but the reality is that URL parameters work for both request methods.